# One or multiple meta-tags?

Tags: html, meta-tags, meta, html-head

I just realized I have two `meta` tags in my HTML `head`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no">
```

Do both work when there are multiple? Should I merge them? Is it just as good with having multiple meta-tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [definition of the `meta` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element). It says:

> Exactly one of the `name`, `http-equiv`, and `charset`, attributes must be specified.

So your two example `meta` elements couldn’t possibly be merged, because then the `meta` element would have the `charset` *and* the `name` attribute, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

It is completely normal to have multiple meta tags, also you can't merge them according to the answer of unor.